# *.desktop files opening in Kate

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I've downloaded and am playing with the new Neon release of KDE. When I activate an item from the Kickoff menu, though, it opens up a `*.desktop` file in the Kate text editor instead of launching the item. What's the issue?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `*.desktop`  file?
I Think the clue might be in there.

Answer (score 5):

### Background

I encountered this bug with a clean installation of 32-bit Kubuntu 16.10. After allowing updates to the system:

1. with Dolphin I browsed to `remote:` (**Network**)
2. I opened **Add Network Folder**
3. I expected a launch of `knetattach` (**Network Folder Wizard – KDE Network Wizard**)
4. instead, a `.desktop` file was opened by Kate.

I installed Thunar 1.6.11, browsed `/usr/share/applications/` and found files, with representative names such as `KNetAttach`, behaving as expected.

Browsing the same directory with Dolphin, I found `org.kde.knetattach.desktop` and other `.desktop` files misbehaving; Dolphin failed to execute the required files.

#### Unix & Linux Stack Exchange

There's the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40027/13260) to *KUbuntu 10.04 / Dolphin File Manager: Is there a way to make .desktop files display the filename the same as the NAME= in the metadata?* – relevant to one of the symptoms that were observed in my case, but not a solution to the execution problem.

#### Super User

There's the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/918015/84988) to *KDE launcher opens .desktop files in Kate* but what's suggested there did not work around the execution problem in my case.

### The solution in my case

[The reply](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=224&t=131103#p351635) to *.desktop files are opened with text editor • KDE Community Forums* refers to a 2015 topic:

- *How do I unset default to open .desktop in a text editor?*

– I took a hint from [a 2016 reply from mfrandsen](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=224&t=129445#p356168).

`nano ~/.config/kiorc`

The file comprised two lines,

```
[Executable scripts]
behaviourOnLaunch=open
```

I edited the second line to read:

```
behaviourOnLaunch=execute
```

– then saved the file.

Immediately after the save, Dolphin behaved as expected.

Comment: After trying to find an answer, as I foolishly thought open meant to open the program I was trying to open, I needed to change it to execute.  This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

@Ryan-muller I've been testing this with a `*.desktop` file.

Here's the contents of my `*.desktop` file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gedit
Comment=Gnome Text Editor
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/apps/text-editor.png
Exec=/usr/bin/gedit
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=false
Name[en_US]=Gedit
GenericName[en_US.UTF-8]=Gedit
Comment[en_US.UTF-8]=Gedit
```

Comment: OP wants to start a program and not editing a file.

Comment: I am well aware of the question, thank you...
I only took `gedit` as an example.
What I've tried to mention earlier, is that this is a desktop shortcut. Ryan could edit the `*.desktop` file at the `Terminal=false` or `Terminal=true` and `NoDisplay=false` or `NoDisplay=true` variable to change the starting behaviour of the app he is trying to start. See the next comment for the rest... this comment hasn't got enough characters left.

Comment: In another case he might have seen a dialogbox mentioning the question where the app, file or shortcut he is trying to open has to be started with, choose `Kate` and forgot to untick the option in this dialogbox, to `always start this type of file with this application`.